# JScrollPane seems to work incorrectly in right-to-left orientation but I'm not quite sure how

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, look-and-feel

My head gets so messed up working with this right-to-left stuff that I'm not even sure where the problem is, but essentially, I found scroll bars to seem "not quite right" when set to right-to-left orientation. I boiled this down to a test program, which works like this:

1. The scroll bars start at UP and LEFT (which feels wrong) and you can see purple.
2. If you resize the window to fit everything, you see that the red is in the upper left.
3. If you resize the window smaller and move the scroll bars to UP and LEFT, you get purple, which seems wrong.
4. If the scroll bars are UP and RIGHT, you get the red.
5. Swiping on the mouse moves the scroll bar in the right position but seems to move the contents in the wrong direction.

I can't tell which bits are backwards and which bits are right, but it seems vaguely correct that the viewport start at the upper right, but the scrollbar being on the left is surely inconsistent. However, if I do try to flip the rendering of the scroll bar, the bar itself doesn't get painted, as if Aqua has detected me trying to cheat somehow.

`AquaScrollBarUI` does not contain a single call to `isLeftToRight()`, but maybe the scroll bar is fine and it's the pane itself which is wrong?

I assume this is a Swing bug, so I'll probably be reporting it, but is there an elegant solution to this mess? I am writing a custom look and feel which subclasses Aqua, so that I can put this sort of fix as close as possible to Aqua.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScrollPaneOrientationTest implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ScrollPaneOrientationTest());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JPanel view = new ViewPanel();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(view);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ViewPanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable {
        private static final int SIZE = 1000;
        private final Paint paint = new GradientPaint(new Point(0, 0), Color.RED, new Point(SIZE, SIZE), Color.BLUE);

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(paint);
            ((Graphics2D) g).fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 8;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 400;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your test program is working fine for me, starting from UP & RIGHT and showing the right content when scrolled. I'm using Java 1.7.0_45.

Comment: `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(paint);..` should best be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); ((Graphics2D) g).setPaint(paint);..`

Comment: @AndrewThompson But I'm filling the entire view, so wouldn't I paint over anything the superclass paints anyway? In any case, that panel is just to provide something that changes, so that you can see which way the scrolling is working.

Comment: @Narmer 1.8.0_05 here, on Mac OS X. I will also note that 1.8.0_05 on Windows seems to start the scrollbar on the right and move the view left when I drag the scrollbar left, i.e. the exact opposite behaviour of what I'm seeing here.

Comment: @Trejkaz weird behaviour. I'm on Windows btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I'm going with initially. I guess I'll accept my own answer if a long time passes with no better options.

```
public class HaquaScrollPaneUI extends AquaScrollPaneUI {
    @NotNull
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration") // called via reflection
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent component) {
        return new HaquaScrollPaneUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected MouseWheelListener createMouseWheelListener() {
        return new FixedXYMouseWheelHandler();
    }

    protected class FixedXYMouseWheelHandler extends XYMouseWheelHandler {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event) {

            if (event.isShiftDown() &&
                    !scrollpane.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {

                // fixes mouse wheel over scroll pane
                event = new MouseWheelEvent(
                        event.getComponent(), event.getID(), event.getWhen(),
                        event.getModifiers(),
                        event.getX(), event.getY(),
                        event.getXOnScreen(), event.getYOnScreen(),
                        event.getClickCount(), event.isPopupTrigger(),
                        event.getScrollType(),
                        -event.getScrollAmount(),
                        -event.getWheelRotation(),
                        -event.getPreciseWheelRotation());
            }

            super.mouseWheelMoved(event);
        }
    }
}

public class HaquaScrollBarUI extends AquaScrollBarUI {
    @NotNull
    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration") // called via reflection
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent component) {
        return new HaquaScrollBarUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics graphics, JComponent component) {
        if (fScrollBar.getOrientation() == Adjustable.HORIZONTAL &&
                !fScrollBar.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {

            // fixes painting direction
            Graphics2D graphicsCopy = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
            try {
                graphicsCopy.translate(fScrollBar.getWidth() - 1, 0);
                graphicsCopy.scale(-1, 1);
                super.update(graphicsCopy, component);
            } finally {
                graphicsCopy.dispose();
            }
        } else {
            super.update(graphics, component);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected TrackListener createTrackListener() {
        // fixes mouse behaviour
        return new FlippedTrackListener();
    }

    private class FlippedTrackListener extends TrackListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseReleased(flipEvent(event));
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mousePressed(flipEvent(event));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseDragged(flipEvent(event));
        }

        // These ones aren't used, but I figured it would be sane
        // to override them anyway, just in case.

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseClicked(flipEvent(event));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseEntered(flipEvent(event));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseExited(flipEvent(event));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event) {
            super.mouseWheelMoved(flipEvent(event));
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
            super.mouseMoved(flipEvent(event));
        }

        private MouseEvent flipEvent(MouseEvent event) {
            if (fScrollBar.getOrientation() == Adjustable.HORIZONTAL &&
                    !fScrollBar.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {

                int x = fScrollBar.getWidth() - 1 - event.getX();
                int y = event.getY();
                Point scrollBarLocationOnScreen = fScrollBar.getLocationOnScreen();
                int xOnScreen = x + scrollBarLocationOnScreen.x;
                int yOnScreen = y + scrollBarLocationOnScreen.y;
                return new MouseEvent(
                        event.getComponent(), event.getID(), event.getWhen(),
                        event.getModifiersEx(),
                        x, y, xOnScreen, yOnScreen,
                        event.getClickCount(), event.isPopupTrigger(), event.getButton());
            } else {
                return event;
            }
        }

        private MouseWheelEvent flipEvent(MouseWheelEvent event) {
            if (fScrollBar.getOrientation() == Adjustable.HORIZONTAL &&
                    !fScrollBar.getComponentOrientation().isLeftToRight()) {

                int x = event.getX();
                x = fScrollBar.getWidth() - 1 - x;
                int y = event.getY();
                Point scrollBarLocationOnScreen = fScrollBar.getLocationOnScreen();
                int xOnScreen = x + scrollBarLocationOnScreen.x;
                int yOnScreen = y + scrollBarLocationOnScreen.y;
                return new MouseWheelEvent(
                        event.getComponent(), event.getID(), event.getWhen(),
                        event.getModifiersEx(),
                        x, y, xOnScreen, yOnScreen,
                        event.getClickCount(), event.isPopupTrigger(),
                        event.getScrollType(), event.getScrollAmount(),
                        event.getWheelRotation(),
                        event.getPreciseWheelRotation());
            } else {
                return event;
            }
        }
    }
}
```